# How to display the sliced image in an axes in matlab gui?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I have sliced an image using `mat2cell()` function. And I'm able to display all the sliced images in `subplot`'s together. But I want to display the same in GUI using `axes` . This is the image I wanted to show in `axes` .

[image]

This is the code I used to slice the image:

```
K = imresize(J,[128 128]);
C = mat2cell(K,[64,64],[64,64]);

%plotting

figure;
subplot(2,2,1),imshow(C{1});
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(C{2});
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(C{3});
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(C{4});
```

I don't know how to display these 4 images in a single `axes`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `imshow` as you would in any script. Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-programmatic-gui-example.html) for a simple demonstration by Mathworks. You can use the same ideas, displaying images instead of surface plots. If you need more specifics please provide more details as to what you want/tried, because your question is very broad as it is now. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the command `axes`. Here there are an example and instructions- http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/axes-menus-and-toolbars-in-programmatic-guis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible to add more than one image on a single axes.
I run your code and I've got the impression that your goal is to divide the original image into 4 pieces then to mix them and obtain a new image.
If so, what about to take the 4 pieces (the 4 cellarrays) and generate a new matrix and then to display it on a single axes?

```
a=imread('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg');

f=figure('unit','normalized','name','ORIGINAL IMAGE');
% My image is not BW
a(:,:,2:3)=[];
imshow(a)

K = imresize(a,[128 128]);

C = mat2cell(K,[64,64],[64,64]);

f=figure('unit','normalized','name','SPLIT IMAGE');
fp=get(gcf,'position')

subplot(2,2,1),imshow(C{1});
subplot(2,2,2),imshow(C{2});
subplot(2,2,3),imshow(C{3});
subplot(2,2,4),imshow(C{4});

tmp1=C{1,1};
tmp2=C{1,2};
tmp3=C{2,1};
tmp4=C{2,2};

TMP=[tmp1 tmp3;tmp2 tmp4];

f=figure('unit','normalized','name','NEW IMAGE');

ax=axes

imshow(TMP,'parent',ax)
set(gcf,'position',fp)
```

**Original image**

[image]

**Split image**

[image]

**New image**

[image]

Hope this helps.